# C# Замедление цикла

Tags: c#, for

Возможно ли замедлить цикл так, что бы мы увидели например, как появляются новые цифры в консоле при пересчете массива(не спрашивайте зачем мне такой, у меня свои тараканы) - как анимация, только в консоле. Если есть специфические классы, буду рад узнать

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(100)`?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можете просто просить поток, в котором выполняется программа, поспать некоторое время. Ну вот так, к примеру:

```
while (true)
{
    // Какие-то вычисления
    Console.WriteLine("Вывести вычисления");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); 
}
```

А если ваша программа делает какие-то дорогие вычисления, то вы можете заметить, что результат выводится не каждые полсекунды, а каждые `0.5 + времяНаВычисления` секунды.

Чтобы выводить результат **как можно быстрее**, **но не раньше, чем через определенный промежуток времени**, можете воспользоваться таким кодом:

```
int timeToSleep = 500;
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
while (true)
{
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();

    // Какие-то долгие вычисления

    Console.WriteLine("Вывести вычисления");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeToSleep - (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Мы перед тем, как начинать вычисления, засекаем время, а после просим поток поспать `timeToSleep - времяЗатраченноеНаВычисления` миллисекунд.